# Should I use normalize.css in my Bootstrap project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, normalize, css-reset

I can't figure out if I need to add the [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) stylesheet in my bootstrap project. I'm using the latest version of bootstrap, v2.3.2.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

No, you shouldn't.

A modified version of normalize.css [is already included](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/less/bootstrap.less#L16) in Bootstrap 2.3.2. [Here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/less/reset.less) it is.

**UPDATE:** [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-normalize) makes this even more explicit, and now they use the original code, not their fork.

**UPDATE: (Bootstrap 4)**

> For improved cross-browser rendering, we use [Reboot](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/) to correct
>   inconsistencies across browsers and devices while providing slightly
>   more opinionated resets to common HTML elements.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#reboot

Comment: I dont have any idea what less is and it was confusing me so im using the baisc version of twitter bootstrap. it only has bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css files. couldnt find any style resets their

Comment: The normalization rules in `bootstrap.css` start at line 43 and end at line 222. You see that comparing `reset.less` with `bootstrap.css`. I'd suggest to start using less or at least to have an idea about what's its purpose. Finally, you can create customized builds using the tool: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html

Comment: Hmm got it now. So you mean i should start using the full version of bootstrap that inckudes less. is there any good source where i can learn less?

Comment: ive downloaded the full version of bootstrap but i cant see any of the .less files attached in any of the html files of the documents :s

Comment: plus there are so many weird files in the folder that dont even open on my computer lol :) should i just ignore them for now?

Comment: I'd suggest using the less version. Less docs: http://lesscss.org/. Having the [source distribution](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/master), less files are in `less` subdir. PS: free to accept/upvote my answer, too :)

Comment: I tried voting but it says i need more reputation for that.:) Your answer was really helpful. Thank you. Im not familiar with less and i dont have enough time to learn it as deadline's near and i have to wind up this project. so i'd stick to the normal version for now. but im really interested in learning how less works. Ill start working on it asap.

Comment: As both the question and answer reference bootstrap 2, just to be completely clear, this is still the case for bootstrap 3 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/less/normalize.less