# Rails Sass: variables are not passed with @import

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a rails project which uses twitter bootstrap and sass. The scss files are structured into folders so I have
a better overview. Now I want to define a file for global variables which contains my colors etc. and pass those values down to other files so I have less redundant code. While all code is properly imported and applied,
variables don't work.

Here is the current setup:

stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree
 */


/*
stylesheets/
|
|– base/
|   |– _reset.scss       # Reset/normalize
|   |– _typography.scss  # Typography rules
|
|– components/
|   |– _buttons.scss     # Buttons
|   |– _messages.scss    # Nachrichten
|   |– _dropdown.scss    # Dropdown
|
|– helpers/
|   |– _globals.scss     # Sass Variables
|   |– _functions.scss   # Sass Functions
|   |– _mixins.scss      # Sass Mixins
|   |– _helpers.scss     # Class & placeholders helpers

//more files omitted
|
|– vendors/
|   |– _bootstrap_and_overrides.css   # Bootstrap
|   |– _scaffolds.scss   # Bootstrap

|
|
`– main.scss             # primary Sass file
*/
```

I'm not using the =require method as it does not allow the use of variables and mixins (which I'd like to use).

I also use a main.scss which contains all the imports.
    stylesheets/main.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@import "helpers/globals";

@import "base/normalize";
@import "base/grid";
@import "base/typography";

@import "components/buttons";
@import "components/tables";
//other files omitted
```

The helpers/globals.scss contains the color definitions:
    stylesheets/helpers/globals.scss

```
$background-light : #4e4d4a;
```

The file component/tables.scss is supposed to use that variable.

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > {
  tr, td, th {
    background-color: $background-light;
  }
}
```

According to most information on the web and the official SASS-guide this should work as I declared the variable and import the according file before the file that uses it. Certainly, the variable is not found:
`Undefined variable: "$background-light"`.

The whole procedure seems rather simple but I'm running out of ideas. Do I need to set something in my environment files or do I need to change my application.css.scss? Or might bootstrap interfere here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Edited spelling, formatting and grammar.

Comment: On a side note - since [CSS specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) is in the order declared (new rules win against an old rule with the same selector) you want to add your normalization at the very top - otherwise it may nuke out your actual styles. But in this case you can remove `@import "base/normalize"`  since [bootstrap ships with it own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286189/should-i-use-normalize-css-in-my-bootstrap-project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting above, I've recently had some experience with assets not working as expected.  The recommendation I received was to use:

```
rake assets:clobber
```

This will clean up the pipeline.

https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: This seems to fix my problem. Also seems a bit cleaner than copying files. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Try removing `*= require_tree` from your `application.css.scss`. Using `require` doesn't work well with sass files, especially when combined with `@import`.

Don't forget to import/require your `main.scss` file when you remove require_tree.

https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note

Comment: I made the according changes but the error is still there. Could it be a problem with my gem versions? I use the following versions:

sass (3.2.19)  
sass-rails (4.0.5)  
bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.2)  
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)

Comment: ^ I have also used this approach in my rails projects and it works.

Comment: @mandulis I don't know anything about the gem versions. Try simplifying your application, by removing all other styles etc till you get it working. Try adding a simple rule in your imported file, just to make sure that it's actually loaded, like `body { background: #f00; }`

Comment: Alright, I tried your idea. I removed all files but the bootstrap ones and the globals and added a new test file using one of the variables from globals. That worked like a charm. Now I can add the old files in step by step and see where it goes wrong. I will post the answer as soon as I find the source of the error.
This approach would have been my last resort anyway. I just thought I made a mistake in the setup.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem although I am not sure what caused it. After I removed all files except the main.scss and the _globals.scss I added a test file using one of the variables and only put these two imports into my main.scss (and the bootstrap ones). That worked as expected. Then I returned all the old files step by step and it still worked. My guess is that the asset pipeline was not compiled correctly and removing all files temporarily fixed that. I will try to reproduce the error and post the result  here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

`@import` is incompatible with `= require`. Replace and remove any `= require` even if you think you've commented it out.

Comment: Wow, yup. This was my issue. Thanks!!