# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Users#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working a Rails app (Rails 6.0.3.4 and Ruby 2.6.3) and am getting this error:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Users#index
```

with the extracted source pointing to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

I have changed the `config.assets.debug` in the `config/environments/development.rb` folder to false. And there was no change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thru [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187407/rails-sass-variables-are-not-passed-with-import)

I remove `*= require_tree` and ran `rake assets:clobber`.